# How to put the text inside of a plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot this function,

```
cη0111ax[V_, X_] := 1/2 E^(-(1/2) Re[V X^2]) V^3 Abs[X/V]^2;

Plot[cη0111ax[4, X], {X, 0, t}
  , PlotRange->{{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, Frame->True
  , PlotLegends->{TextString@Row@{"X=", 1, "\n", "η=", cη0111ax[4, 1]*100, "%"}} 
  , Filling -> Axis
]
```

I use `TextString Row@{"X=", t, "\n", "η=", cη0111ax[4, t]*100, "%"}`
to add a text that denotes the value `x` and `cη0111ax[4, t]` at point `t`.
However, I can't put it inside of the figure. Adding a frame for text is also preferable. What can I do, thanks!

Moreover, hot to control the text format.

Answer (score 2):

As my reputation is too low to comment, I'd like to respond with an answer:

You can use `Placed` and `Scaled` together with `PlotLegends` as following:

```
Plot[c\[Eta]0111ax[4, X], {X, 0, t},PlotRange->{{0, 2}, {0, 1}},Frame->True, PlotLegends->Placed[{TextString@Row@{"X=", 1, "\n", "\[Eta]=", c\[Eta]0111ax[4, 1]*100, "%"}}, Scaled[{0.8,0.9}]],Filling -> Axis]
```

The coordinates passed over to `Scaled` define the (relative) position of your legend.

Comment: Great,Thank you!